# How do I test if a parameter has been passed into a template in XSLT v 2.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm currently trying to upgrade from XSLT 1.0 to XSLT 2.0. I had the following in one of my templates that used to work with XSLT 1.0 :-

```
<xsl:template name="some_t">
  <xsl:param name="some_numeric_param"/>
  <xsl:if test="$some_numeric_param != ''">
    <xsl:attribute name="some_name">
      <xsl:value-of select="$some_numeric_param"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, there are three cases in which I call this template :-

```
<xsl:call-template name="some_t">
  <xsl:with-param name="some_numeric_param" select="floor(number(./@attr1) div 20)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

When I do this, basically the inner template will only create the attribute called "some_name" iff the attribute called "attr1" is given in the source document.

Also, another situation in which I might call this is without this param :-

```
<xsl:call-template name="some_t">
</xsl:call-template>
```

So What I basically want it to do is that when I pass in a parameter then create an attribute, otherwise don't. Whether my stylesheet is correct or not, this worked in XSLT 1.0 but in XSLT 2.0 it gives an error that says :-

```
Error on line 195 of movwin.xsl:
  XPTY0004: Cannot compare xs:double to xs:string
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

Any help? I'm using the Saxon 9.4 processor.

Comment: owagh, If you *really* want to learn XSLT 2.0, then read and pay attention to the best answer -- the one by Michael Kay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a good idea in 2.0 to declare the types of your parameters. If you're expecting an integer, declare `<xsl:param name="p" as="xs:integer"/>` - and don't try comparing it to a string. If the integer might or might not be present, declare it as an optional integer like this: `<xsl:param name="p" as="xs:integer?"/>` and use the empty sequence (written `()`) as a 'null value'. You can then test whether a value has been supplied using `test="empty($p)"`.

Your 1.0 code works because when you compare a number to a string, the string is converted to a number. The empty string converts to NaN, and NaN compares not equal to anything. I think -- though I would need to check -- that that still works in 2.0 if you run in backwards compatibility mode, which happens if your styesheet specified version="1.0".

Comment: so I would need to do something like <xsl:call-template name="some_t"> <xsl:with-param name="some_numeric_param" select="()"/> </xsl:call-template> ?

Comment: Either that, or give it a default value using select="()" in the xsl:param element itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're comparing a number to a string.

Try changing:

```
<xsl:if test="$some_numeric_param != ''">
```

To:

```
<xsl:if test="$some_numeric_param">
```

**EDIT**

To also handle `$some_numeric_param = 0` try:

```
<xsl:if test="string($some_numeric_param)">
```

There's no need to do the `!= ''` comparison.

Comment: But this will give false if some_numeric_param = 0. I want it to be able to differentiate between when I have passed the param and when I haven't.

Comment: This works! I'll accept steven's answer though since he was first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try coercing the input param into a string:

```
<xsl:if test="string($some_numeric_param) != ''">
```

xslt 2.0 is more strongly typed than 1.0.